# FFmpeg, Icecast and ice_name in Cyrillic

Tags: ffmpeg, cyrillic, icecast

To set stream names (**-ice_name**), I need to use Cyrillic characters. But on Icecast server I get hieroglyphs.

If I use software other than ffmpeg, then everything is displayed fine. But I need to use ffmpeg exactly.

Here's the source:

```
"c:\ffmpegrec\ffmpeg.exe" -i rtmp://... -fflags nobuffer -vn -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192K -content_type audio/mpeg -f mp3 -ice_name "Имя стрима" -ice_description "Описание стрима" -ice_public 0 -password ... icecast://...
```

All this is run through a .bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting charset on that mount point in Icecast configuration like this:

```
<mount-name>/mount</mount-name>
    ...
    <charset>UTF8</charset>
</mount>
```

Change UTF8 to whatever encoding you have (cp1251 I guess).